# Using a userform object to save a file

Tags: vba, ms-word

I need to have the VBA code save a file, that was created from a template, to a specific directory with a specific name.  Example:  \Partial path\ plus a subdirectory selected in the userform \ plus another bit of info from a different userform.
I can get it to save to the partial path, but adding the subdirectory and the filename is where I'm stuck.
This was the last thing I tried...

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 FileName:="X:\Directory\" & strSubDirectory & strUserText ".docx"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What version of Word are you using?  SaveAs2 only works in Word 2010 or later.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `"\"` and some `&`s in your statement.  Also depending on your version of Word, you might not be able to use `SaveAs2` as it was introduced with Word 2010.  The code below works using `SaveAs`.  **Note: This code assumes the subdirectory already exists**

```
Private Sub SaveDocument()
    Dim strSubDirectory As String
    Dim strUserText As String
    Dim myPath As String

    strSubDirectory = "SubTest"
    strUserText = "Test"
    myPath = "C:\Test\" & strSubDirectory & "\" & strUserText & ".docx"

    ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:=myPath, FileFormat:=wdFormatXMLDocument
End Sub
```

The different types of FileFormat can be found at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839952.aspx

Comment: `.docx` isn't aadequate to `wdFormatXMLDocument`. Also check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff839952.aspx !

Comment: @LS_dev Not sure what you're trying to point out.  I've tested the above code on Word 2007, 2010, and 2013 without any issues.

Comment: Yes, because when Word starts reading file states that it is not `wdFormatXMLDocument` and try to guess correct format. If you want to create a true `.docx`, use `wdFormatXMLDocument`. Use `wdFormatXMLDocument` to create `.xml` documents.

Comment: You can also specify filename without extension, so Word automatic adds correct one. Or you can omit FileFormat and Word will guess correct format from extension.

Comment: @LS_dev, I don't think I buy into that explanation.  An xml uses the FileFormat `wdFormatFlatXML`.  You can test it out easily by creating a macro with a new document and save it as a XML.

Comment: Shame on me!!! (I didn't even properly read my previous comment). My escuses. `docx` format is `wdFormatXMLDocument` type. Sorry!!! :-( I would downvote myself if I could...

Answer (score 0):

Did you make sure that your `strSubDirectory` etc. contain the path separator?  If not, you need to include this in your `FileName` string:

```
ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 _
    FileName:="X:\Directory\" & strSubDirectory & "\" & strUserText & ".docx"
```